# explode data mysql into selected item

Tags: php, mysql

i have data in mysql which is

### id|merchant_id|card_support|

1 | 000001    | visa,mastercard,amex |
2 | 000002    | visa,mastercard      |

php:

i think something wrong in php here:

```
<?php $qryselect = mysql_query("select * from cc_merchant"); ?>
  <span style="font:25px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666666; font-weight:bold;">CREDIT CARD TYPE</span>
            <?php 
            $getcard = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryselect);
            $card = $getcard['card_support']; 
            $cctype = explode(',',$card);
            ?>
            <select>
            <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php for ($a = 0; $a < sizeof($cctype); $a++) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cctype[$a]; ?>"><?php echo $cctype[$a]; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

what is the problem here...i want to display the data into selected item after i explode it...but it seem nothing to display...please help..

Comment: It seems as if your database schema might need some tweaking; you shouldn't have to store the card types together.

Comment: but the card type from the multiple selected by admin..

Comment: you want to display all data of table ? or specific marchat id ?

Comment: if you var_dump($card) before `explode`ing, what do you get?

Comment: You should have a **card type** table, which contains a list of the card types, and simply reference them in any table that needs them.

Comment: i want to display card_support into select list

Comment: use $card = $getcard['card_support'];  `print_r($card);` to check what values are in $card

Comment: yoavmatchulsky, it get NULL

Comment: @xana, then something is wrong with your schema. What you got in $getcard?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky it get bool(false)

Comment: @xana, then either your query is wrong (the table doesn't exist), or that table is without data. you always need to check that `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns a valid recordset

Comment: i already double check it....nothing problem beside that php that i asked....

Comment: i think i already know now what the problem...it because of i using the variable $qryselect twice....btw,thanks @yoavmatchulsky

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it is preferred to use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) over [sizeof()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php), as sizeof() doesn't mean the same thing in most other languages. Additionally, it is recommended to use `foreach()` to iterate through arrays:

```
foreach($cctype as $c){
    echo '<option value="'.$c.'">'.$c.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: how this answer is relevant to his question?

Comment: also thanks to @Samuel Cook for the relevant answer...